# Thread function with passed by reference vector is slow to start

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, reference

I've been looking at C++0x threads and have this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
void TestFunc(const vector<int>& vVec)
{
    cout << "in"<<endl;
}

int main()
{

    int sizer = 400000000;

    vector<int> vTest(sizer);
    for(int f=0; f<sizer; f++)
        vTest[f] = f;


   cout << "V created." << endl;

   thread one(TestFunc, vTest);

     one.join();    

}
```

As you can see it just passes a vector to a thread.
The thing I don't understand is that there is a pause after the message "V created" appears. Originally this (I assumed) was the vector being copied for use in the function.
To stop this I passed by reference instead but this made no difference.

The delay seems to be proportional to the size of the vector which indicates that it is still copying (or doing something with the array).
If I try the same experiment without threads and just call the function directly the delay is there when passing by value but not when passing by reference as I expected.

I tried the same using Boost threads instead of C++0x (even though I've read that they are much the same) and got the same result.

Is there some reason for this behaviour or have I missed something blindingly obvious?
Thanks.

Sorry, posted the wrong test code. Corrected.
Edit: Added includes as requested.

Compiled with:
g++44 -std=c++0x -lpthread tester.cpp -o test
...as I have GNU 4.4 installed along side the standard GNU compiler that comes with my Linux (CentOS) which doesn't support C++11.

Comment: the most expensive part of TestFunc is the trace, not the parameters  passing. it seems that C++0x does not support creating threads

Comment: @Mahesh: On what system? This is just 400 million and will fit comfortably in a 32-bit int.

Comment: @BruceAdi: In C++11 threads are mandated by the standard, and at least gcc-4.6 does support them, and they work - I use them every day.

Comment: @BruceAdi: If you're using `g++`, did you compile with the `-pthread` option?

Comment: And, this is one case in which using `endl` is the perfectly correct thing to do. :-)

Comment: Can you add relevant includes to your example? Also, how are you compiling?

Comment: Includes and compile command added to help any one in the future, issue ressolved thanks all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm just speculating, since you haven't posted the version of the code that uses threads, but I would suspect your problem is that, by default, `std::bind` (or `boost::bind`) make copies of all the arguments you bind. To avoid this, you can use `std::ref` or `std::cref`.

To make this concrete, you're probably using `bind` like this:

```
std::bind(TestFunc, vTest)
```

Instead, you should use it like this:

```
std::bind(TestFunc, std::cref(vTest));
```

Comment: This seems kind of clunky to me. Is there no way for `bind` to divine that the function wants a reference and so that it should store a reference?

Comment: +1 I just tested it with your code, and you are right. When using _std::cref_, the delay disappears. Nicely spotted.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I'm not sure that would even be desirable. The behaviour expected from a closure (which, essentially, is what `bind` is) is that the objects passed in as arguments "survive" for as long as the closure exists. This would not be the case if `bind` only stored references for all parameters of a reference type. Or, to look at it another way: Copying all arguments is a safe default behaviour. Passing references carries a certain danger and should therefore be requested explicitly; in addition, the explicit `ref` or `cref` is a clear flag for anyone doing maintenance later on.

Comment: Used ref and it worked. I used it like this:    thread one(TestFunc, ref(vTest));   So in terms of threads it seems that varaibles are copied by default unless you use ref(). I'm looking up ref() at the moment.

Comment: @MartinB: BTW, I tested it too, and you're right. It also occurs to me that storing references when the function being bound takes a reference would likely lead to surprising results in many cases as the bound variables might go out of scope and be destroyed before the bound function was called. And I see that's exactly the thought you had too.

Comment: @Columbo: Yes, the arguments are copied by default. `std::thread` has the same semantics in this regard as `std::bind`.

Comment: @Columbo: Indeed, threads *copy* all their arguments. It's the sensible thing to do if you think about it. If you really want references, use `std::ref` or std::cref`, as you already discovered.

Answer (score -1):

Where are the threads here? Looks like the `for` loop is causing the *delay* you are referring to. Nothing unusual here - as you are assigning a vector of size 200000000.

Comment: -1: This would be a great answer if the delay weren't between seeing 'V created.' and 'in'.